# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'current_page'

Tags: python-2.7, django-templates, django-cms

I have created my first page successfully but when I clicked on  view on site it is showing

```
Error : 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'current_page'
```

I don't Know whats wrong, please sugggest.
When I am using direct html via view it is loading page but It is showing error while I am trying to render template.
I am using following version:-

```
'django-cms==3.3.1',
'django==1.9.8',
'python==2.7.6'
```

My file descriptions as follows :-
setting.py :

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
```

]

url.py :

```
    from django.conf.urls import include,patterns,url
from django.contrib import admin
    from django.conf import settings

    # urlpatterns = [
    #     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # ]
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
    ]
```

Traceback -

```
    Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 174, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 172, in get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 160, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 137, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 95, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 206, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 197, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 992, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 959, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 173, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 197, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 992, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 959, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 69, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 992, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 959, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/classytags/core.py", line 146, in render
    return self.render_tag(context, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/classytags/helpers.py", line 41, in render_tag
    value = self.get_value(context, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py", line 490, in get_value
    page = _get_page_by_untyped_arg(page_lookup, request, get_site_id(None))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py", line 78, in _get_page_by_untyped_arg
    return request.current_page
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'current_page'
[25/Sep/2016 12:19:26] "GET /?edit&language=en-us HTTP/1.1" 500 146389
```

Comment: Hello, please update your question with the following: Django version, django-cms version, python version and a full traceback. Thanks :)

Comment: @Paulo - I have updated my question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the djangoCMS middleware classes from your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting.

Here's a list of the middleware from djangoCMS:

```
[
    'cms.middleware.utils.ApphookReloadMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
]
```

And here's how your settings should look like:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'cms.middleware.utils.ApphookReloadMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
)
```

You can find more information on how to setup a project by hand in our [docs](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/how_to/install.html#configuring-your-project-for-django-cms).